# The solution of the contour integral for $\epsilon =+1$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I understand the solution for $\epsilon =-1$. And I am trying the solve this question for $\epsilon =+1$. This is important for me. I want really to learn perfectly because I am continuously seein' such questions.

**Please check my answer for $\epsilon =+1$**

**The question** is that

Find the integral $$I(n,\epsilon)=\int_{-i \infty}^{+i \infty} \frac{e^{\epsilon z}}{(z+\epsilon)^n}$$

The integration is taken along the imaginary axis,

an integer $n\gt 0$ and $\epsilon \in \{-1,+1\}$

**solution:**

I need to consider the countour integral $$\oint_C \frac{e^{z}}{(z+1)^n}dz$$

The integral is counterclockwise (i.e closing the left)

Let's solist this integral into 2 pieces;

$$\int_{iR}^{iR} \frac{e^z}{(z+1)^n}dz +iR \int_{\pi /2}^{3\pi /2} e^{i\theta}\frac{e^{Rcos\theta} e^{iRsin\theta}}{(Re^{i\theta}+1)^n}d\theta$$

Next I need to show that the magintude of the second integral vanishes as $R\to \infty$ for $n\gt 0$

The magintude is bounded

$$R\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi /2}\frac{e^{Rcos\theta}}{R^n}d\theta= \frac{1}{R^{n-1}}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{-Rsin\theta}d\theta\le 2\frac{1}{R^{n-1}}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}e^{-R\theta/\pi}d\theta\le \pi/R^n$$

By the residue theorem, the contour integral equals to $2i\pi$ times the residue at the pole $z=-1$

$$\frac{1}{(n-1)!}[\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}e^z]_{z=-1}=\frac{1^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}e^{-1}$$

So I $$\int_{-i\infty}^{+i\infty}\frac{e^z}{(z-1)^n}dz=2\pi i\frac{1}{(n-1)^!}e^{-1}$$

Please show my mistakes. Thank you:)

Comment: There is no $(-1)^{n-1}$ factor in the answer.  Hint: what is the derivative of $e^z$?

Comment: The derivative of $e^z$ is $e^z$ again @RonGordon

Comment: Also, the analysis of the vanishing integral has to be a little more careful than what you posted.  Look at the inequality of the sin - where is it valid?

Comment: OK, correct.  So what is the $n-1$th derivative of $e^z$?

Comment: Again the same $e^z$ @RonGordon

Comment: Right!  So that $e^z$ evaluate at $z=-1$ is...?

Comment: Hmm then $-e^{-1}$ @RonGordon

Comment: From where did you get the negative sign?  You must have this condition where negative signs pop up out of thin air, because in reality, there is no negative sign.  It's just $1/e$.

Comment: Okay I corrected this. Now every thing is right? What are my other mistakes? @RonGordon

Comment: Looks OK to me.

Comment: That's, Is the integral parts of the solution correct? Thank you very much:)@RonGordon

Comment: What kind of mistakes for the analysis of vanishing integral? Can we correct there as well? @RonGordon

Comment: You have : $\displaystyle\int_{\frac \pi 2}^{\frac {3\pi}2} e^{2R\theta/\pi} d\theta\geq \pi e^R$

Comment: How? I dont understand. Please can you be more clear? @girianshiido

Comment: Well, in fact you have errors just before the last inequality in your substitution.

Comment: While I was writing there, I was confused too much. But I cannot see my mistakes and I dont know how to do this. Please can you help me correcting there? @girianshiido

Comment: First, I see a $\cos$ and then a $\sin$, yet the lower and upper limits didn't change (minus the typo $3\pi$ instead of $3\pi/2$). What substitution did you use?

Comment: Yes I used first cos and then sin. For $\epsilon =-1$, it was solved in such way. How do I need to do in order to correct it? @girianshiido

Comment: $\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} e^{R\cos(\theta)}d\theta=\int_0^\pi e^{-R\sin(\theta)}d\theta=2\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-R\sin(\theta)}d\theta$, then use the fact that $2\theta/\pi \leqslant \sin(\theta)$ when $0\leqslant\theta\leqslant\pi/2$

Comment: I corrected. Everything is okay? Isnt it? @Girianshiido